# How to create a BizTalk Application btaproj

Tags: biztalk, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, biztalk-2016

I am using BizTalk 2016 and I want to enable build from VSTS.

Build fails because it asks for some *.json files.

After some investigation I reached the conclusion that I have to create
a btaproj file. [Add a BizTalk Server application to Visual Studio Team Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt800828.aspx)

I installed Feature Pack 1 but there is no option for BizTalk Application project.

How can I create a btaproj file?

Comment: See [BizTalk Server Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559046.aspx)

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition?

Comment: What Edition of BizTalk Server are you using?

Comment: I use Biztalk2016.The tasks are (Build solution, Copy files, Publish Artifact). I managed to move forward by using the steps described in the first answer. I face some permission problems, VSO agent service must build the app as administrator. I am searching now on that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Which build agent did you use? You own build agent or VSTS Hosted agent?

Comment: I have installed a VSO agent on the local machine. I can see this agent in VSTS under default.

Comment: I found it. In project's properties, under Build Events -> Post-build events there were some commands, probable written by VS. these commands were causing an error during building. If I was starting VS as admin, they were not causing any error and building was finished correctly. By removing these commands, agent could run build my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you select .NET Framework 4.6.1 in create new project dialog?

[image]

fr step by step instructions, please follow https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/05/02/bts-2016-feature-pack-i-continuous-deployment-walkthrough/

Comment: thanks I followed the steps, but I get an error when building the Biztalk application. VSO agent must build the application with administrative rights, else it fails. I get the same errors when building the app directly from within VS2015.

Comment: @user3417479 Do you use private build agent? Try to change build service account to the administrator account (local service > Double click build agent service> change account)

Comment: I found it. In project's properties, under Build Events -> Post-build events there were some commands, probable written by VS. these commands were causing an error during building. If I was starting VS as admin, they were not causing any error and building was finished correctly. By removing these commands, agent could run build my app.

Answer (score 1):

I used the steps described in [usman-shaheen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7722/usman-shaheen) post

Then I had an error during building. In project's properties, under Build Events -> Post-build events there were some commands, probable written by VS. These commands were causing an error during building. If I was starting VS as admin, they were not causing any error and building was finished correctly. By removing these commands, agent could run and build my app.

Comment: please add following Build arguments in Build definition in VSTS. it will prevent per/post build events to run

/p:PreBuildEvent=;PostBuildEvent=